# Nothing happens when I click .jnlp file on IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, java-web-start, jnlp

I tried to use Java Web Start for call my program first time. It is successful in my computer and other computer, but one of the others have a problem.

In this computer, when I click the link in IE to open .jnlp file, nothing happened.  I also tried to find the temporary file of IE, and click it. It will open IE and display a blank window, and nothing happens. But I click on the .jnlp file which is the local file, it is successful.

How should I solve the problem with this computer?

Thanks.

Windows 7 / IE 11 / jre7

Comment: I have some questions about your issue. Have you tried open other files in IE?Do them work in IE? You say that "click the link in IE to open .jnlp file", how the link will open the .jnlp file?Have you checked that if there is any error in the console?

Comment: I put the jnlp file on the Tomcat Server. In other computer, the jnlp file could be launch successfully. So I think that it has no problem on the file. Where is the console? How can I check it? Thanks.